# getting latest photos from friends not working

Tags: facebook-fql, photo

I tried getting the latest photos fo my friends using a method described here:
[FQL - Can i get photos of my friends posted this week](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6515533/fql-can-i-get-photos-of-my-friends-posted-this-week)

At first it seemed to be working fine but then I noticed that some of the photos of my friends weren't being fetched even though they had a higher timestamp (the photos were being sorted by *created* field from *photo* FQL table)...
After a bit of debugging I noticed that the problem is in

```
SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN 
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

if I pass a short list of my friends' IDs they are being sorted correctly, but when I pass a complete list not all friends are included in the query result...

Any ideas why this isn't working? Are there any limits on how many values can be passed in a "SELECT XXX FROM YYY WHERE ZZZ IN (?)" query?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit seems to be about 5000 records returned in any part of an FQL query.

Assuming you have fewer than 5000 friends, you could cut down on the number of albums returned by modifying your query to inspect the `modified_major` column to only return albums that have had a photo added in the period of interest. You could alternately look at the `modified` column to return any album modifications.

Also, it looks like `aid` and `pid` are on the path to deprecation. New development should use `object_id` for maximum compatibility.

So to get all albums that have had a photo updated since 2012-10-01, you could use this query:

```
SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN 
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND modified_major > 1349049600
```

In your outter query change `aid` to `album_object_id` and `pid` to `object_id`

Comment: I tried the following FQL query: SELECT pid, aid, owner, link, src_big, src_small, created, modified FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN 
  (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN 
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
    AND modified_major > 1349049600 ORDER BY modified_major desc
  )
ORDER BY modified desc 
but it still doesn't include all photos (the query you provided return only 3 albums in my case, replacing SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() with one of my friends IDs gives shows me that there are other albums that are not fetched in the original query)

Comment: NVM, the query is probably correct, but there's a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/102161909944898, I will accept your answer nevertheless since it's a better way of getting the photos anyway

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't affected by the bug when I tested, but that's Facebook. Make sure you file a repro on the bug if you haven't already.